# Error 404 for file download without browser redirection?

Tags: http-headers, http-status-code-404, mime-types

on a website I display links to PDF files. 
When the first time call for a file arrives, the request gets redirected to a php-script that generates and returns the file. Additionally, it saves the file to the linked location so next time it will be directly availibe. I send the pdf **mime type** to make the browser open a **download dialog instead of redirecting**.

Due to reasony beyond my control, one out of 20 files cannot be generated.

**How to respond?**

Error 404 or 500 would direct the browser to an error page, while sending a mime-type would let the user download an empty / defect pdf file. Is there an established best practise? How to let the user know that a file link is broken, yet keep him on the site without redirect?

Comment: To me 404 makes most sense - the file could not be generated (you can customise your 404 error page to reflect that) and therefore can not be found.

Comment: @GermannArlington Thank for your comment. Yet it does not solve the redirection problem.

Comment: Which redirection problem? The first attempt redirect to generation script?
 
P.S. Sending pdf mime type will NOT prompt user to "saveAs" if the user have pdf plugin installed, if you want to enforce the "saveAs" prompt you need to send UNKNOWN mime type.

Comment: Thank you for your hint with the unknown type! The situation I ask for a best practise solution for is that I do not want the user to be redirected (as he would be not if the download link was valid.) SO I could always send some data to avoid redirection, but that would end up in a defect pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows:

If you have link to file, for example:

```html
<a download href="/files/document.pdf">Click to download</a>
```

And if you don't want the browser redirect to blank/error page if the file doesn't exist, just reply with 204 without any content.

Nothing will happen, the user will stay where he is without redirection.

In php it would look something like this:

```php
if (!readfile("/files/document.pdf") {
    http_response_code(204);
    die();
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, as it does not provide a way to "let the user know that a file link is broken" - it merely makes the link unresponsive (although a few clicks on a link that is unresponsive certainly makes it seem broken). How to display a message on the page that says "that file is not available", but do normal file download otherwise?

Comment: You can do that only with async download with Javascript (Fetch, jQuery...) and handle response. With a href link, if file is not found, you can only be redirected to 404 or make link unresponsive.

Comment: My solution, which only works for very specific circumstances where you can make an api call to check whether the later download will work or not, was to use a button to make that api call, and then click a hidden download link in javascript when successful, or display an error if not. I agree there is no practical solution in general that I have found that leverages the browser file downloading features without redirection on failure, I did use 204 in that api call to indicate a later download call would give a 404, so your answer was helpful.